# How to list all available printers from terminal?

Tags: command-line, printing

I need a command to list available printers in my Ubuntu.

The printers list could be installed or shared?

This list also should state the state of the printer .

Any Help to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The Command `lpstat -p` will list all available printers for your Desktop .

And whether or not they are available ( the state of them) .

Comment: Also works on macOS (Ventura 13.0)

Comment: As of 2023, brian_p's answer is more correct.

Answer (score 16):

If you just want the printer names:

```
lpstat -p | awk '{print $2}'
```

To see their names and print queues:

```
lpstat -p | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 lpq -P
```

Answer (score 3):

> I need a command to list **available** printers in my Ubuntu.

I have bolded **available** because the OP presumably means that.

Neither `lpstat -p` nor `lpstat -t` list **all** printers **available** on the local network. Both commands only show **local** (often called permanent) printers. Both appear to have gained some traction as inadequate responses to the query.

As of 2022, `lpstat -e` or `lpstat -l -e` give **all available** on the local network.

Answer (score 2):

For the most detailed information about all available printers including local and lan printers, you can use `-t` option with [`lpstat`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/lpstat.1.html)

It tells you the following:

1. Scheduler information
2. Default printer
3. Addresses of the printers
4. Enabled status with timestamp
5. Accepting jobs status with timestamp
6. If a printer is currently printing

Here is the sample output

```
> lpstat -t

scheduler is running
system default destination: HP_Ink_Tank_Wireless_410_series_1C5045
device for Deskjet-Ink-Adv-2010-K010: hp:/usb/Deskjet_Ink_Adv_2010_K010?serial=CN12C11MQH05MB
device for HP_Ink_Tank_Wireless_410_series_1C5045: implicitclass://HP_Ink_Tank_Wireless_410_series_1C5045/
Deskjet-Ink-Adv-2010-K010 accepting requests since Saturday 30 April 2022 10:45:04 AM
HP_Ink_Tank_Wireless_410_series_1C5045 accepting requests since Monday 02 May 2022 01:54:54 PM
printer Deskjet-Ink-Adv-2010-K010 is idle.  enabled since Saturday 30 April 2022 10:45:04 AM
printer HP_Ink_Tank_Wireless_410_series_1C5045 now printing HP_Ink_Tank_Wireless_410_series_1C5045-202.  enabled since Monday 02 May 2022 01:54:54 PM
HP_Ink_Tank_Wireless_410_series_1C5045-202 user           679936   Monday 02 May 2022 01:54:54 PM
```