# all network printers are automatically listed

Tags: printing

[Print Manager in Ubuntu 14.04 automatically adds all network printers to print view](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481240/print-manager-in-ubuntu-14-04-automatically-adds-all-network-printers-to-print-v)

has got no answers and is also quite old. 
I have this problem with 16.04 xenial.

Can anyone tell me how can I list only those printers that I have manually added? I could do it in 14.04 pretty calmly, but something came up which broke it - perhaps systemd because many services are automatically started even if they are manually stopped.

Moreover, when I stop the printing service cups using systemctl, then I cant add any printer, not even my local ones !

Comment: Posting as comment because I am not 100% sure but I think shared printer discovery is done by the service `cups-browsed`.  You could try stopping this service, then deleting the printers you want, and see if they reappear.  I had to disable this service before because of a bug in it, and there was no ill effects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation)

Comment: See guntbert's answer in the suggested duplicate. There is no accepted answer, but his worked for me.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/416996/349837) isn't helpful? I would take a look to `lpoptions` and `lpinfo`.